# How can I merge :conditions for my SQL query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's presume that I have two different conditions

```
:conditions => ["base == ?", self.search_text]
```

and

```
:conditions => ["status = ?", "#{self.status}"]
```

Is there any way to merge these conditions into one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [#scoped](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb#L28) method:

```
base = Model
base = base.scoped(:conditions => {:base => params[:search_text]}) if params[:search_text].present?
base = base.scoped(:conditions => {:status => params[:status]}) if params[:status].present?
@results = base.all(:order => "created_at DESC")
```

Although I linked to the 3.0 ActiveRecord code, this also works under 2.3.

Comment: I have to join 2 tables so I added :joins param to scoped

Answer (score 3):

You can define a method to merge the conditions. For example:

```
first_condition = ["base == ?", self.search_text]
second_condition = ["status = ?", "#{self.status}"]

def merge_conditions(array = [])
   conditions = array.map {|a| "(#{a.first})"}.join(' AND ')
   params = array.inject([]) {|new, a| new += a[1..a.size]}
   params.insert(0, conditions)   
end
```

and use

```
merge_conditions([first_condition, second_condition])
```

This will return

```
["(base == ?) AND (status = ?)", self.search_text, "#{self.status}"]
```

I don't know if this is the best way, but it works!

Comment: Just did this myself. Looking for a built-in way. I guess not :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure I understand what you're looking to do, but it sounds like what you want are [`named_scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html)s (which were changed to [`scope`](http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/)s if you're using Rails 3).

In your model you can define dynamic named scopes:

```
named_scope :base, lambda { |value| { :conditions => { :base => value } } }
named_scope :status, lambda { |value| { :conditions => { :status => value } } }
```

And then you can use these scopes as finders:

```
results = Model.base(self.search_text).status(self.status) to join your conditions.
```

You could add as many conditions as you wanted this way.

Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: This is not quite that I need sure I can write such conditions manually but I need some code which merges them and depends on number of conditions

Comment: Oh, gotcha, I misunderstood what you were asking.